# How to use Map with more than one operator

Tags: haskell

is it possible to use `map` with 2 operators in it like `map ((*2)+3) [1,2,3,4]`? If is yes how? i want to make a function that `apply (x*2)+3` on a list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You `map` a single function. But that function can do whatever you want. Your example can be given as an anonymous function for example:

```
map (\n -> n * 2 + 3) [1,2,3,4]
```

But you can also use function composition, which is likely more readable for a case like this where your function is a case of "do one thing, then the other":

```
map ((+3) . (*2)) [1,2,3,4]
```

This in turn is equal (by the so-called "functor laws") to

```
map (+3) . map (*2) $ [1,2,3,4]
```

Which I personally find a little more readable.

Comment: Thanks that helped me much, know im trying to apply map ((+3) . (*2)) for all odd numbers and map ((+3) to all even.

I tried it with cases but it does only check if the first number is odd or even. Here my Code `oddandeven :: Int -> [Int]
oddandeven = 
\t -> case t of
    x
      | odd x -> x:map ((+1).(*3)) (oddandeven x)
      | otherwise -> x:map(`div` 2) (oddandeven x)`

Comment: Then you'll have to define a function of type `Int -> Int` that does the check on odd or even and does the appropriate thing - then `map` it over the list.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is easy to first introduce a lambda expression here:

```
map (\x -> (x*2)+3) [1,2,3,4]
```

This will do exactly what you want. You can perform "*function composition*" with the [**`(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c`** function](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:.), and thus write this as:

```
map ((+3) . (*2)) [1,2,3,4]
```

Here you thus can see it as a "chain" of functions, where we pass the input to the rightmost function (here `(*2)`), and then the result is passed to the leftmost function (here `(+3)`).